# motherload – a common mistake or slang word?

Tags: slang, errors

I am a bit unsure about how the word "motherload" should be seen – as a common mistake or slang word or both.
I've encountered the word the first time [in a recent Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2017/may/17/george-lazenby-on-bond-sex-and-the-60s-they-had-the-pill-i-was-a-handsome-guy), but to my surprise it was later changed to "mother lode":

> This article was amended on 17 May 2017. An earlier version spelled
>   “mother lode” as “motherload”.

[After having seen something like that in a book](https://books.google.de/books?id=Sy5LAAAAYAAJ&q=%22motherload%20of%22%20prince&dq=%22motherload%20of%22%20prince&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)

> Since the dramatic emergence of Prince, however, Minneapolis has yeilded

(sic !)

> a rich motherload of new soul music talent.

I am not sure if many uses of "motherload" are actually because of ignorance. The word often appears in a context, even scientific one, which does not really "allow" the usage of slang. The only online dictionary that lists "motherload" seems to be Wiktionary. So I wonder if the intentional use of "motherload" as a slang word is actually rare?

Comment: A quick google suggests that **mother lode** is correct. Since your other quote isn't sourced (other than "in a book"), and contains another error(!), I wouldn't give it too much credibility.

Comment: I wonder if you'll get a better answer than [the one on grammarist](http://grammarist.com/spelling/mother-lode/). But a  "mother lode" vs motherload search will give you lots of links. Including [this one](http://www.kuediting.com/ads/classifieds/lode-vs-load-and-why-you-and-your-mother-should-care/) for a smile.

Comment: I've added a link to Google Books in my question for the Prince quotation.

Comment: The term "mother lode" (with or without the space) refers to a major vein of the desired mineral found in, eg, a gold mine.  Popularized in the "gold rush" periods in California and Alaska.  I don't recall ever seeing "mother load" used in this sense in a reliable publication, though I certainly might have overlooked it at times.  I have seen "mother load" used as a pun for, eg, the angst that a mother places on an adult offspring.  I would consider "mother load" to be incorrect, when used to refer to the real or metaphorical mineral vein.

Comment: Note the presence of "(sic!)" and the misspelling of "yielded" in the Prince article, suggesting that the use of "motherload" there may have been some sort of a pun or such.

Comment: The (sic!) was added by myself, I'll make that clear in my post. Actually, I've seen "motherload" in scientific publications, even in the context of mines. Google Books shows some results.

Comment: Though "professional publications" in the context of mines would be the better term, the "scientific publications" were about other things.

Comment: @HyperventilatingValedictorian - mother load in a non standard spelling or a spelling mistake according to: http://www.beedictionary.com/common-errors/motherload_vs_mother_lode. The fact that it can be found also in academic texts doesn't change the fact that  the standard and more common spelling is motherlode. Usage might make it a regular  spelling with time.

Comment: Note that if "yielded" was misspelled one would not anticipate the correct spelling of other words.

Comment: @Josh Sure – since I had first looked up "motherload", it was clear to me that "mother lode" is the actual standard and "motherload" either a misspelling or pun on that word. My question was rather about whether the ignorance or the deliberate pun prevails in usage - which is, after all, admittedly a bit speculative.

Comment: @Hyperventilatin - yes , that would be sort of "opinion based" issue, which is off-topic here.

Comment: From the links supplied by Laure above: "Mother load, a common misspelling, sort of makes sense, but it’s not the conventional term, and many readers will view it as incorrect."  "In most cases, though, ignorance rules. 'Mother-lode' has become 'motherload' in many cases because people simply don’t know the difference." That actually answered it for me, though it is not really "authorative". I'll try to avoid off-topic tendencies in the future though.

Comment: "authoritative", sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Motherload" is a non standard spellings  of the more common "motherlode".

As suggested by the following [source](http://www.word-detective.com/2015/04/motherlode/) load and lode were originally the same term. Through  the centuries they developed different connotations and lode was more commonly used from the 17th century to refer to a rich vein of mineral ore, from which the more common spelling "motherlode"  from the 1920s especially in a figurative sense:

> - ***If I sound a bit blasé when I say that, it’s because “lode” and “load” were the same word to begin with. They are, as the Oxford English Dictionary (OED) puts it, “etymologically identical,” one being merely a “graphic variant,”*** a slightly different spelling, of the other. That’s not to say that the words are interchangeable; the spelling difference between”lode” and “load” has led to slightly different meanings over the years.
> - ***“Lode” and “load” first appeared in Old English, drawn from the same Germanic roots that eventually also produced “to lead” in the sense of “to guide, conduct.”***  “Load/lode” was also influenced by the separate word “lade,” meaning “to load or burden,” which is now obsolete except in such terms as “bill of lading,” the noun “ladle” and the participle “laden” (“Laden with debt, Larry played Lotto.”).

.......

> - The original sense of “load/lode” in Old English was “way, route” or “means of transport.” As the forms diverged in meaning in the 13th century, “load” developed in the sense of “that which is carried,” now familiar in everything from the “load” of a truck to the “debt load” that prompted Larry to gamble.
> - “Lode,” however, developed in the “guide, signal” sense, giving us “lodestar,” a bright star in the sky (usually Polaris) used to navigate ships, and “lodestone,” the naturally magnetic mineral “magnetite,” used in primitive compasses.
> - ***In the 17th century, “lode” began to be used to mean a rich vein of mineral ore***  in the earth that, once discovered, would guide miners in their excavations. ***Starting in the 19th century, an unusually large and rich lode was known as a “motherlode”*** (“The lode called the Esmeralda, the most prominent and apparently the mother lode of the district, runs with the meridian.” 1863).
> - ***Beginning in the 1920s, a rich source of anything was figuratively known as a (or “the”) “motherlode” (“The pages of the T.L.S. were the very mother-lode of academic inanity.” 1960).***

(www.word-detective.com)